# Exigências de design para publicação de aplicativos na AppStore

Tags: ios, ionic

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo Ionic, tenho conferido a documentação de layout/design para aplicações AppStore, mas gostaria de saber se existe alguma exigência de design que devo me preocupar.
Exemplo: meu aplicativo pode ser recusado caso eu use o titulo do header alinhado para a direita?

Se essa pergunta é fora do escopo do site, me informem que eu apago, por favor, não consegui encontrar um assunto que detalhe exatamente as exigências de design da AppStore.

Comment: Tenta publicar, se tiver algo errado a Apple vai entrar em contato com você falando o que houve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O aplicativo na AppStore costuma ser recusado por mal funcionamento, por exemplo um botão que fica metade dele para fora da tela, ou a tela gira e os componentes visuais ficam todos tortos. Mas em questão de alinhamento de texto não chega reprovar por causa disso não, senão limitaria muito o trabalho dos designers.